# ICU implementation code for BreakIterators

Tags: c++, icu

I was looking to modify the ICU source code, but it's quite impenetrable to me and I was unable to find the piece that I was looking for.

I was hoping to find the code (and hopefully some explaining comments/documentation) on the BreakIterators implementation. Does anyone know where in the ICU C++ source code this is?

Comment: Also you should file a ticket with whatever you are trying to modify

Answer (score 2):

See http://site.icu-project.org/repository

And specifically:
[brkiter.cpp](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/source/common/brkiter.cpp)